# Magento 2.3: How to process HTML content from the wysiwyg in frontend?

Tags: magento2.3, blocks

I created a widget that has a field for text as wysiwyg value. When I call up this value `$block->getData('field_name')` in frontend, I get something like:

```html
<p>Content goes here</p>
<ul>
    <li>Some text</li>
    <li>Some text 2</li>
</ul>
```

While the value should look like this:

Content goes here

- Some text
- Some text 2

How can I add HTML processing to my block? Thank you!

Comment: are you using $block->escapeHtml ? if so, then don't do it :) just echo the value and it should work, unless the tag values are encoded.

Comment: No, I call it so: <?= $block->getData('field_name') ?>

Comment: can you add your code for block?

Answer (score 0):

Using magento way try this to print your html

```
<?= /* @noEscape */ $variable_name  ?>
```

And you can also print your html using **echo**

```
<?php echo $var; ?>
```

**Update**

```
$str = '&lt;a href=&quot;https://www.w3schools.com&quot;&gt;w3schools.com&lt;/a&gt;';
echo html_entity_decode($str);
```

[Link here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_html_entity_decode.asp)

Comment: I've tried both variants, but it does not work for me ;( I know, normally it should works without any special changes..

Comment: try this html_entity_decode it may helps you

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen someone get a static block using getData so I suspect that is the issue.

The typical way of loading CMS block content is like so:

```
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="myBlock">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">myBlock</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

Then you can call the block inside your template with `$block->getChildHtml('myBlock')`